# How to show that $\chi_{[0,\infty)}(x)$is not integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral

How to show that $\chi_{[0,\infty)}(x)$is not integrable?

**My idea:**

to use the following proposition:

Let the nonnegative function $f$ be integrable over $E.$ then $f$ is finite a.e. on $E.$

But I am not sure, I feel that my function is finite even though its domain is infinite. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just choose the simple functions $f_n(x) = \chi_{[0,n]}$. Then $\int f_n d\mu = n+1$ so the supremum over the $f_n$ will go to infinity

Comment: why the integral is $n +1$? Are you using the definition of integrability for bounded functions or nonnegative ones?@BrevanEllefsen

Comment: $f_n$ is a simple function taking on $r = 1$ nonzero values, for which we have $\int f_n d\mu = \sum_{k=1}^r a_i \mu(A_i) = \mu([0,n]) = n+1$ when working with the Lebesgue Measure. It is rather easy to show the integral of a simple function with respect to the Lebesgue Measure is the same as its Riemann Integral by essentially this same proof idea.

Comment: I am sorry, I still do not understand what are the $A_{i}$'s and why measure of the interval from $[0, n]$ is $n+1$ and what are the small $a_{i}$'s of our $\chi$? could you please explain this for me?@BrevanEllefsen

Comment: Given our discussions in your posts over the last week, I would suggest you review the prior sections in the textbook you are reading more carefully, as you should not be having this much difficulty; either you are rushing a bit too quickly or you are lacking some prerequisite knowledge

Comment: I should correct my comment above, as I should have written $n$ instead of $n+1$ in both places. Slight mistake on my part. That being said, $\mu([0,n])$ is an interval of length $n$ so has measure $n$, the $a_i$ are the finitely many values of a simple function, and $A_i$ is the set on which the simple function equals $a_i$.

Comment: I think part of my problem is that the definition of $\chi_{[0, \infty]}$ was not very clear for me @BrevanEllefsen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Show by definition that for *any* given positive integer $n$, $\chi_{[0,\infty)}(x)\ge \chi_{[0,n]}(x)$ for all $x$.
2. Show by Theorem 10 in Royden that for each $n$.

   $$
       \int \chi_{[0,\infty)}\ge \int \chi_{[0,n]}
    $$
3. Show by Definition in Section 4.2 that for each positive integer $n$, 
   $$
   \int \chi_{[0,n]} = 1\cdot m([0,n])=n
   $$ 
   Note that $\chi_{[0,n]}$ is a *simple function*.
4. Combine 1--3 to show that $\int \chi_{[0,\infty)} =\infty$ and thus $\chi_{[0,\infty)}$ is not integrable.

---

Note: bounded measurable functions are NOT necessarily Lebesgue integrable. You have just seen an example. But bounded measurable functions *over a set of finite measure* are.